# iOS Control Center: seek through timebar, add "like" and "share" button

Tags: ios, control-center

iOS' built-in music player allows users to:

1. Seek through timebar
2. Like
3. Share

From Control Center.

However, the documentation doesn't mention anything about it: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPNowPlayingInfoCenter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MPNowPlayingInfoCenter)

Can I do the same for my app?

Comment: No, you can't. These functions are only available for the in-built music spp

Comment: I saw some apps that allow seeking through timebar from Control Center. Are they using the built-in Music Player? Can I use Music Player for my own app?